# Client configuration in Electron

Tags: electron

I am quite new to Electron and I have two questions regarding configuration of my app.

1) Looking for a way to store client configuration (similar to app.config of .Net Apps).

Why I need this:
I am working on a desktop electron app. This app will be distributed to a number of machines and each of them need to have different configuration values.

2) Need a way to package electron app with predefined configuration for a specific machine.

Example:

- Machine 1's config: MachineID='M01', MachineType='A'
- Machine 2's config: MachineID='M02', MachineType='B'

Appreciate the support!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For me it was the same but I needed to save settings about the window so I made a `settings.js` file and stored my settings in there.

For you your settings file would contain something like this:

```
exports.machineType = 'A';
```

And you would get it in your app like this:

```
var settings    = require('./settings.js');
var machineType = settings.machineType;

if (machineType == 'A') {
    // Do things for machine type A.
} else {
    // Do things for machine type B.
}
```

Comment: Thank you Mike, i got the basic concept from your example.

Comment: @WahajRashid No problem :). If my answer helped you please accept by clicking the tick below the vote count https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers